# BigQuery Blockchain Dataset is Missing Data?

Tags: google-bigquery, bitcoin

I'm trying to do some analysis on the richest Bitcoin wallets, and discovered that the BigQuery dataset is missing a ton of data.

For example, take a look at the #1 richest account currently.

The wallet address is: "3D2oetdNuZUqQHPJmcMDDHYoqkyNVsFk9r"

If I look this wallet up in [blockexplorer](https://blockexplorer.com/address/3D2oetdNuZUqQHPJmcMDDHYoqkyNVsFk9r), or any online blockchain data source, I see that the wallet has received ~3.29 million and sent ~3.16 million for a net balance of 138,660 BTC.

Yet when I look any transcations where 
`inputpubkeybase58 == '3D2oetdNuZUqQHPJmcMDDHYoqkyNVsFk9r'`, I get zero results back.

Here is the query I wrote as a test.

```
SELECT i.input_pubkey_base58
from `bigquery-public-data.bitcoin_blockchain.transactions`
  JOIN UNNEST(inputs) as i
where i.input_pubkey_base58 = '3D2oetdNuZUqQHPJmcMDDHYoqkyNVsFk9r'
LIMIT 100
```

Why are none of the 3.16 million BTC sent being referenced in the above query?

Please correct me if I'm saying or doing something stupid. Thanks!

Edit: I can find the transactions where `o.output_pubkey_base58 == '3D2oetdNuZUqQHPJmcMDDHYoqkyNVsFk9r'` no problem. But I am not looking for the total BTC received, I am looking for the transactions where BTC was sent from the wallet, as per the above query.

Update: To shed more light on this discrepancy, [I tried to examine transactions where BTC was sent from the aforementioned address on blockchain.com](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/3D2oetdNuZUqQHPJmcMDDHYoqkyNVsFk9r?sort=0&filter=1). Most of the recent transactions where BTC was sent from the wallet could not be found in BigQuery. [For example,  I couldn't find an Oct. 22, 2018 transaction where 2,000 BTC was sent to 1Kr6QSydW9bFQG1mXiPNNu6WpJGmUa9i1g.](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/6d0da34d69693ae81169a0cc3cd65847929939617d3a8cf41ef3d02971857a3e)

```
SELECT o.output_pubkey_base58, i.input_pubkey_base58, o.output_satoshis
FROM `bigquery-public-data.bitcoin_blockchain.transactions`
   JOIN UNNEST(inputs) as i
   JOIN UNNEST(outputs) as o
WHERE 
transaction_id ='6d0da34d69693ae81169a0cc3cd65847929939617d3a8cf41ef3d02971857a3e'
```

I was able to find some of the older transactions dated in 2017 like

```
SELECT o.output_pubkey_base58, i.input_pubkey_base58, o.output_satoshis
FROM `bigquery-public-data.bitcoin_blockchain.transactions`
   JOIN UNNEST(inputs) as i
   JOIN UNNEST(outputs) as o
WHERE 
transaction_id ='29dd29b8d1647c766f3fad233fe7a0c026fbb9f42544d96c917f6b028667907a'
```

But the results show null for i.input_pubkey_base58

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try below

```
SELECT COUNT(1)
FROM `bigquery-public-data.bitcoin_blockchain.transactions`,
UNNEST(outputs) AS o
WHERE o.output_pubkey_base58 = '3D2oetdNuZUqQHPJmcMDDHYoqkyNVsFk9r'
```

this will give you 5417 transactions

Comment: Hey thanks but that's not what I'm looking for. I can find the outputs to the address, but it's the inputs from the address that are missing.