# Bitcoin in BigQuery: blockchain analytics on public data wrong ommited results

Tags: google-bigquery, blockchain, bitcoin

I am trying to use the Bitcoin in BigQuery to extract bitcoin transactions related to some addresses.
I tried the below query to retrieve this information, but I always get empty results.

```
SELECT
    timestamp,
    inputs.input_pubkey_base58 AS input_key,
    outputs.output_pubkey_base58 AS output_key,
    outputs.output_satoshis as satoshis
FROM `bigquery-public-data.bitcoin_blockchain.transactions`
    JOIN UNNEST (inputs) AS inputs
    JOIN UNNEST (outputs) AS outputs
WHERE outputs.output_pubkey_base58 = '16XMrZ2GNsrUBv3qNZtvvPKna2PKFuq8gQ'
    AND outputs.output_satoshis  >= 0
    AND inputs.input_pubkey_base58 IS NOT NULL
    AND outputs.output_pubkey_base58 IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY timestamp, input_key, output_key, satoshis
```

Also, when I change the address to one with more transactions, I get results but with some transactions omitted.

I do not know if I am writing something wrong or what. Can anyone help, please?

Thanks

I saw a similar question in a previous post and tried what was suggested but it did not work: 
[BigQuery Blockchain Dataset is Missing Data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53293896/bigquery-blockchain-dataset-is-missing-data)

I am expecting to get 3 address when trying 
WHERE outputs.output_pubkey_base58 = '16XMrZ2GNsrUBv3qNZtvvPKna2PKFuq8gQ'

and 2 addresses when chenge the condition to consider the address in the input side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am expecting to get 3 address when trying WHERE outputs.output_pubkey_base58 = '16XMrZ2GNsrUBv3qNZtvvPKna2PKFuq8gQ'

Your expectations are correct, but the issue here is that the dataset you are using is outdated and has been migrated to `bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin`. Updates to the data are being sent to the new version of this dataset, whose schema is better aligned with our other cryptocurrency offerings.

To get started run below to see that expected data is there

```
#standardSQL
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.transactions`,
  UNNEST(outputs) AS output,
  UNNEST(output.addresses) AS address
WHERE address = '16XMrZ2GNsrUBv3qNZtvvPKna2PKFuq8gQ'
```

with output

```
Row f0_  
1   3
```

Comment: Thanks for that. The query you are provided is running perfectly. I will read the new data description and modify my code accordingly. Thanks

Comment: If anyone needs the updated query:  SELECT 
 block_timestamp AS timestamp,
 in_address AS input_key,
 out_address AS output_key,
 output.value AS satoshis
FROM `bigquery-public-data.crypto_bitcoin.transactions`
 JOIN UNNEST(outputs) AS output
 JOIN UNNEST(inputs) AS input,
 UNNEST(output.addresses) AS out_address,
 UNNEST(input.addresses) AS in_address
WHERE out_address IN (..........)
 AND output.value>=0
 AND in_address IS NOT NULL
 AND out_address IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY timestamp, input_key, output_key, satoshis